# Is it possible to add an Ajax action on a button define in a twig view template?

Tags: views, 8, ajax

I have a view for which I customized the views-view-field...html.twig template. On each row, I added a first button A which opens a modal with two buttons: *Button B* to confirm the action and *Button C* to cancel the action.

When the users click on *Button B*, I would like to programmatically create new content and close the modal. I imagine I should use AJAX.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score -1):

So i found the solution using webform module